# Django object update using htmx and SingleObjectMixin

Tags: django, htmx

I'm using htmx for the first time. I have a table where each cell is a `grade` object. Previous to htmx I made each cell a link to an UpdateView for the object. I am now trying to have the user modify the the object's `score` field directly in the table using htmx. I'm sure I'm doing several things wrong.

My page loads as expected and the table is displayed as expected. when I type in a cell, I get an error `Forbidden 403. CSRF Verification Failed.`

The purpose of this post/question is to figure out how to get past this 403 error.  Having said that, if it turns out that I'm going down the completely wrong path with using a SingleObjectMixin, please let me know.

**View**

```
class GradeChange(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    """ view to handle htmx grade change"""
    model = Grade

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        grade = self.get_object()
        assessment = Assessment.objects.get(grade=grade.pk)
        print(assessment)
        classroom = Classroom.objects.get(classroom=grade.cblock)
        print(classroom)
        if grade.score == "EXT" or grade.score=="APP" or grade.score=="DEV" or grade.score=="BEG":
            grade.save()
            return HttpResponse("S")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("")
```

**template**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Students</th>
          {% for obj in objective_list %}
          <th class="col-2" scope="col">{{ obj.objective_name }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
          <th scope="col">Comments</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for student in student_list %}
        <tr>
          <td >{{ student.student_first }}&nbsp;{{ student.student_last }}</td>
          {% for g in grade_list %}
            {% if g.student.id == student.id %}
            <td><a  href="{% url 'gradebook:updatesinglegrade' g.assessment.pk g.cblock.pk g.pk %}"></a>
              <input type="text" hx-post="{% url 'gradebook:grade-change' g.pk %}" hx-target="" hx-trigger="keyup delay:2s" class="form-control score" title={{ g.score }} name="score" id="input-{{ forloop.counter0 }}" placeholder={{ g.score }} required>
              
            </td>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          <td>
            {% for comms in comment_list %}
              {% if comms.student == student %}
                <a class="grade-comment" href="{% url 'gradebook:addcomment' comms.pk assess_pk class_pk %}">{{ comms.comment|truncatewords:10 }}</a>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </form>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDIT - a solution**
I came across this, which works.

```
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
        event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSRF token must be included in the HTMX POST request. Currently you include it only in the regular form, but the HTMX request is initiated from a child input element where the token is not present. So just include the following `hx-header` attribute to a parent element like the `<form>` or event the `<body>` is a good candidate:

```
<body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I can't get this to work by putting in a parent element but it helps me understand why the js script that I put in my post edit works.

Comment: Strange, because [`hx-headers`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-headers/) is inherited, so putting it on a parent element should work. Anyways, your method is also good.